# WPF: Change GridView cell colors few second when differ in values

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

When the gridview cell's value change, I want to change the background color for few seconds to notify users.
How to implement.
I can change the background color when the value is changed.
But I don't know how to change it back after few seconds.

Comment: try to use Background Worker in WPF. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahakgupta/background-worker-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a timer in the cell change event handler, and set the background color twice. Once the highlighting color and at the end of timer, normal background color.

Here's a full impementation of CellValueChanged on DataGriewView. Check this out once.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx